# AJAX request with if statement for filename called

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm making a quiz using AJAX to refresh each question. Instead of having individual AJAX calls for every different question in the quiz, I was wondering if there might be an easy way to use the same AJAX call but add a digit to the end of the filename each time.

So here is the basic AJAX request:

```
function nextQuestion()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("wordbank").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","question2.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

As you can see the GET request pulls a file called question2.php

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","question2.php",true);
```

This is just a stand-in file at the moment, what I really want to do is something like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","question" i++ ".php",true);
```

OK, I phrased that badly, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this. Essentially I want to have my button bound to the `nextQuestion()` function, but I want to work out a way to generate the next filename based on the one you're currently on.

Is this possible?

Another idea would be to give the button on each page a different ID and have the `nextQuestion()` function take that ID and use it to generate the next file. E.G if you are on question 2, the button would have an ID of `question2`. The ajax would take the last digit (2) and add 1 to it, so the filename called would be `question3.php` - and that is how it would know to move to the next question.

Comment: Looks like should be tagged with javascript, not jquery. Are you using jQuery at least?!

Comment: Apologies, I'll remove it.

Comment: I would use something like `id="question_2"` then you can do something like `var splitID = elm.id.split('_');` and then `var myID = splitID.pop();`

Comment: @cmorrissey this sounds like a good idea, but would you be willing to develop it more and post it as an answer in the thread? Sorry, I understand what you're saying but I haven't used these functions before so it'd be good to see it working, perhaps in a JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go you can now place an ID on any button and have it take you to the correct page.

Your JS

```
function nextQuestion(buttonID)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("wordbank").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
var splitID = buttonID.split('_');
var questionID = splitID.pop();
xmlhttp.open("GET","question" + questionID + ".php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Your Button

```
<button id="question_2" onClick="nextQuestion(this.id)">Go To Question 2</button>
```

or

```
<button id="question_14" onClick="nextQuestion(this.id)">Go To Question 14</button>
```

Comment: This is great, however I've just made it more complicated. I forgot that every question has an answer page too. So the button on Question1 page needs to take you to question1a.php. Then the button on question 1a.php takes you to Q2. Is that still possible with this script?

Comment: If the split is based on a `_`, then it should work as long as the ID is question_1a ?

Comment: @Francesca that's correct what ever is after the last `_` in the id will work

Comment: Perfect, it works. http://fh80.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/fyp-assets/quiz/quiz.php :)

Answer (score 0):

so build a string with the current index you have

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","question" +  i + ".php",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a global var with the current quest and do something like this:

```
var current_quest=1; 
function nextQuestion() 
{
    ...
    xmlhttp.open("GET","question"+current_quest+".php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    window.current_quest++;
    ... 
}
```